# How is value of macro getting change

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int var;
    printf("write the value of var:\n");
    scanf("%d", &var);
#define NUM var

    printf("The value of S is %d\n", NUM);
    var = var + 1; //changing the value of variable 'var'
    printf("New value of S is %d", NUM);
return 0;
}
```

Following is the result...

```
write the value of var:
10
The value of S is 10
New value of S is 11
[Program finished]
```

In this program, I want to make constant the value of variable 'var' once it's entered by user. so, I have defined a macro with macro templet 'NUM' and macro expansion 'var'.
But when I change the value of 'var' on execution time then the value of 'NUM' also get changed. Don't know how?
Actually I don't know that can we use any variable in macro expansion ?

Comment: A macro isn't a variable - it's purely text substitution at compile time.  Your line `printf("...", NUM);` is precisely equivalent to if you had written `printf("...", var);`.  If you want to save the result of a variable set at runtime, assign its value to *another variable*.

Comment: Preprocessor runs early: before the actual compilation starts, thus long before the program runs. In your code, the macro replaces `NUM` with `var` (as if you manually did the change in your IDE).

Comment: With `const int NUM = var;`

Comment: @HolyBlackcat:  means before execution of  program, the NUM get replaced by var and if we change in var then there will be chage in NUM. means it becomes like a simple variable

Comment: In case of ***#define NUM 10*** the num replaced by 10 and whenever we use NUM in program it equals to 10. so, in case of constant macro expansion only, the macro will work. is it so?

Comment: It's not even a variable. The word `NUM` is literally replaced by the word `var`, as text, before your program is compiled.

Comment: @NateEldredge: “it's purely text substitution”: No, it is not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat:  is it same in case of any number at the place of var. like ***#define NUM 10***. If It is so then if we use NUM in program then it's not NUM it's 10. is it right?

Comment: Yes, for any possible value of `NUM`. At the extreme, you could do something like `#define NUM ,10);`, then `printf("%d" NUM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessing is done before the actual C code compilation. It simply textually replaces the token `NUM` with token `var`.

So after the preprocessing your function is:

```
int main()
{
    int var;
    printf("write the value of var:\n");
    scanf("%d", &var);

    printf("The value of S is %d\n", var);
    var = var + 1; //changing the value of variable 'var'
    printf("New value of S is %d", var);
return 0;
}
```

This `main` function is being compiled. As you see the `NUM` has been replaced with `var` and the result is obvious.